# "Ржа", "ржавчина", "ржание" - однокоренные ли слова?

Tags: этимология

"Ржа", "ржавчина" - и "ржание". Слова только созвучны или имеют общий корень?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первые два, без сомнения, родственны. Третье, ржание, только формально имеет с ними звуко-буквенные совпадения, но не может считаться однокоренные из-за разницы в значении. Такие пары слов называют словами с омономичными корнями. Слово ржание - производное от глагола ржать, а он  произошел от  "реветь, ревущий, вой".